# TP-Link TL-WN722N V2 and AP mode (nl80211: Driver does not support authentication/association or connect commands)

Tags: linux, wifi, wifi-hotspot

I've tried to use TP-Link TL-WN722N V2 (`ID 2357:010c`) with AP mode on both Debian and my self compiled buildroot firmware. Using recent kernel (v5.5 and v4.19) and [rtl8188eu module](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git/tree/drivers/staging/rtl8188eu/) from staging and correct firmware `rtlwifi/rtl8188eufw.bin`. Driver get's loaded and possible to use in non-AP mode, but when trying to use it fails with `nl80211: Driver does not support authentication/association or connect commands`:

```
$ cat /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=foo
channel=6
hw_mode=g
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=12345678
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP

# hostapd -dd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
random: Trying to read entropy from /dev/random
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
nl80211: Driver does not support authentication/association or connect commands
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0
nl80211: Remove monitor interface: refcount=0
netlink: Operstate: ifindex=4 linkmode=0 (kernel-control), operstate=6 (IF_OPER_UP)
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 4 iftype 2 (STATION)
nl80211: Failed to set interface 4 to mode 2: -19 (No such device)
nl80211 driver initialization failed.
hostapd_interface_deinit_free(0x76c0d4f0)
hostapd_interface_deinit_free: num_bss=1 conf->num_bss=1
hostapd_interface_deinit(0x76c0d4f0)
wlan0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->DISABLED
hostapd_bss_deinit: deinit bss wlan0
wlan0: AP-DISABLED 
hostapd_cleanup(hapd=0x76f187c0 (wlan0))
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING 
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan0 wasn't started
hostapd_interface_deinit_free: driver=0 drv_priv=0 -> hapd_deinit
hostapd_interface_free(0x76c0d4f0)
hostapd_interface_free: free hapd 0x76f187c0
hostapd_cleanup_iface(0x76c0d4f0)
hostapd_cleanup_iface_partial(0x76c0d4f0)
hostapd_cleanup_iface: free iface=0x76c0d4f0

# iwconfig
wlan0     unassociated  ESSID:""  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Auto  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

I've found many question for Kali Linux (e.g. [Trying to install HostAPD on Kali linux Error = Driver does not support authentication/association or connect commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/564592/trying-to-install-hostapd-on-kali-linux-error-driver-does-not-support-authenti)), but no answer.

Do I need to use out-of-tree kernel module (e.g. https://github.com/abhijeet2096/TL-WN722N-V2, https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver)? These drivers are similar to one in staging, but without cleanup (i.e. I guess functionality is worse, not counting problems with out-of-tree drivers and worse code quality).

And/or some out of tree hostapd driver? These out of tree drivers also refer to some config (probably for old wpa_supplicant/hostapd version) https://github.com/abhijeet2096/TL-WN722N-V2/blob/master/wpa_0_8.conf, but I'd prefer to use recent version.

I haven't set IP for wifi, hope that's not a problem:

```
# ip addr show wlan0
    4: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
        link/ether 50:3e:aa:7d:81:39 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from Larry Finger, maintainer of derived work from Realtek:

> Only very old hostapd is supported by the staging driver, and not very well.
>
> Your best chance is to use the [`v5.2.2.4`](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu/tree/v5.2.2.4) branch pf
> http://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu.git.
>
> This driver uses cfg80211/nl80211 commands and supports the latest hostapd.

source: http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/hostap/2020-May/041657.html

I just wonder, why that cleanup development is happening out-of-tree (having it mainline would be easier for users).
UPDATE: out-of-tree code is that complex that it'd take years to get it in a shape. That unfortunately leads to out-of-tree driver.